# 7 inch tablet emulator configuration with resolution and abstracted lcd density in android

Tags: android-layout

I want to run my application on 7 inch tablet.I have created an emulator to test my application whose configurations are:

- Resolution:1024*600
- Abstracted Lcd Density:160
- MAX VM Application heap size:24
- Device ram size:256.

I have defined different layouts also like:

- layout-hdpi for high density phones
- layout-mdpi for medium density phones
- layout-ldpi for low density phones
- layout-sw600dp=for 7 inch tablet

but it does not show the layout of 7 inch tablet in tablet emulator.
how to resolve this please tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is surely because the Android version of your emulator is inferior to 3.2 which is the first version to support the sw_n_dp qualifier.